# In Spark how to call UDF with UDO as parameters to avoid binary error

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I defined a UDF with UDO as parameters. But when I tried to call it in dataframe, I got the error message "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array) => int)". Just want to know it is expected that the exception mentioned the UDO as binary, and also how should I fix it?

```
val logCount = (logs: util.List[LogRecord]) => logs.size()
val logCountUdf = udf(logCount)
// The column 'LogRecords' is the agg function collect_list of UDO LogRecord
df.withColumn("LogCount", logCountUdf($"LogRecords"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general you cant pass in custom objects into UDFs, and you should only call the udf for non-null rows otherwise there will be a NullPointerException inside your UDF. try:

```
val logCount = (logs: Seq[Row]) => logs.size()
val logCountUdf = udf(logCount)

df.withColumn("LogCount", when($"LogRecords".isNotNull,logCountUdf($"LogRecords")))
```

or just use the built-in function `size` to get the logCount :

```
df.withColumn("LogCount", size($"LogRecords"))
```

Comment: Actually the column will not be null as we have filter logic before this. What the error I got here is mentioned in the question: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1: (array<binary>) => int)

Comment: I see that the udf parameters here you just set it as Seq[Row], so can't we use parameter with types other than Row?

Comment: @TommyTan Sorry I was not aware of Sparks User-Defined-Types (this was removed in Spark 2). Maybe it's possible to pass your UDT to the UDF, but the problem is somewhere else

Comment: It works now for UDO as parameter. But I still have the question on UDO as return value.